# Слэш / в начале ссылки

Tags: html, css

Вообщем скопировал сайт и в начале пути стоит /,например href="/theme/style.css",из-за / в начале  путь указывается неправильно,если убрать,то всё ок.Но там много нужно будет убирать.Как быстро можно выполнить это?Или есть другие варианты?

Comment: sed 's/\/theme/theme/g' как вариант. Если в редакторе, то открыть файлы и 'заменить во всех открытых'
 Ctrl+Shift+H в VS Code, если подводит память.

Comment: У меня саблайм текст

Comment: Есть ещё варианты?Если залить сайт в фтп

Comment: @АндрейНикитин замена работает почти во всех редакторах. Для конкретно Sublime Text не знаю, но не думаю, там оно будет отсутствовать. А вообще вопрос не серьезный, так как можно даже весь ваш код поставить в консоль любого сайта [как строку и там тоже заменить](https://imgur.com/sCNILP0.png).

Comment: Ну в Sublime найти замену во всех открытых файлах. А FTP вообще как здесь поможет? Я предложил sed - это самый мощный инструмент. Какие-то магические заклинания посоветовать вам не могу.

Comment: @void что-то из магических сверху посоветовал :-)